# migrate git repository to bitbucket

Tags: git, bitbucket

I have my code (including a lot of branches) in my Git repository on GIT server in my organization that I want to move to bitbucket. The size of the repo is more than 6 GB, so I want to use Git LFS for my large binary files. How do I migrate my repo to bitbucket?
If I just take a mirrored copy, I cannot add large files to Git LFS and when I push the entire code to bitbucket, it becomes read-only because it has reached the soft and hard quota limit.
If I clone the entire repository, how do I add files to git lfs and then push them to a new bitbucket repository including the branches and tags?

Comment: You will have to rewrite the history of the project, but I don't know how to do that in order to put files into LFS.

Answer (score 2):

Create a new repo in bitbucket.
Configure bitbucket to use lfs.
Lfs should already be configured for lfs if you are already using. Then

```
cd path/to/repo
git checkout master
git remote add bitbucket bitbucketrepourl
git push bitbucket master
```

Comment: This does not help. When I push bitbucket to master, since the size is more than 6 GB, the repo becomes read-only. When I add files to lfs before the last step, I have to push the .gitattributes file first so that LFS can become active. Do you know how can I only push .gitattributes file?

Comment: Maybe try 'git push --all bitbucket' https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserver/importing-code-from-an-existing-project-776640909.html

Comment: 'git lfs push --all bitbucket'